Continuous Discrete State Space Properties
When we have a continuous model that we try to discretize it by using ZOH, if the first state is reachable, then what can we say about the reachability, observability and stability of the discrete state-space model?

We can say that this appears to be a homework question, or perhaps a vague imprecise question that should not be posted.

It was discussed by the lecturer himself during the lecture. He had no intention of any closure, so any discussion would be beneficial. Thank you!

SE is not a discussion forum. It is a question and answer resource.

This is what office hours are for.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
